# selenium webdriver to find the anchor tag and click that

Tags: java, selenium, web-scraping, web-scripting

```
<div id="ContentPrimary">
<ul class="selectors modeSelectors">
    <li><a href="/content/l411846326l1213g/references/" title="">
        <span class="selector">References (27)</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="/content/l411846326l1213g/referrers/" title="">
        <span class="selector">Cited By (2)</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="/content/l411846326l1213g/export-citation/" title="">
        <span class="selector">Export Citation</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="/content/l411846326l1213g/about/" title="">
        <span class="selector">About</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

In this I need to find and click **About** link using Selenium api but I was unable to do it.

what I did is

```
wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver webDriver) {
        System.out.println("Searching ...");
        String s = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ContentPrimary ul li[4] span.selector")).getText();
        System.out.println(s);
        if (Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("About"), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(s).find()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
driver.findElement(By.linkText("About")).click();
```

but its not working

Comment: Please describe what is not working exactly, what browser are you using, and whether an exeption is thrown etc...

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but could helpful for you for your future. You can write the last condition more directly: `return Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("About"), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(s).find()`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In my experience the Selenium API has many flaws in that way. They can mostly only be overcome by reformulating your selectors. For example you could try using a XPath selector to get your element:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'About')]")).click();
```

Also, if you are trying to use the Internet Explorer it might help not to click the element, but instead to simulate pushing the Enter button.
So assumung the Element is found, you could try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("About")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Comment: By the way, instead of `\n`, you can [send an actual Enter](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Keys.html), `.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)`

Comment: Thanks, I improved my answer as you suggested.

Comment: Jeez the sendKeys(Keys.ENTER) does miracles in IE.Thank you for this!

Comment: `Keys.ENTER` is not meaninful if you don't specify where `Keys` was imported from: `from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ExpectedConditions](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html):

```
wait.until(visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("About"))).click();
```

Comment: The link is broken, please, update, if you can, or delete.

Answer (score 0):

Try using xpath to find the ancor then use that object to send an enter key

anchorObj.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);