# Selecting value from <li> dropdown - Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to select a value from a small dropdown that appears to be a "ul"
Here's what I see in Firebug:

```
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="true"       aria-haspopup="true" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button">
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">1</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">2</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">3</a>
```

Here's what I have so far, in Java:

```
 public void selectPhoneType(String option)
    {
        driver.findElement(By.className("caret")).click();
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("dropdown-menu")));
        WebElement element = driver.findElement()
    }
```

Let's say I wanted to **select/click on option "1"**. How would I complete my code? I haven't worked with "li" too much so I tried using a select, which obviously didnt work. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public void selectPhoneType(String option) {
       // Open the dropdown so the options are visible
        driver.findElement(By.className("dropdown-menu")).click();
        // Get all of the options
        List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='dropdown-menu']/li"));
        // Loop through the options and select the one that matches
        for (WebElement opt : options) {
            if (opt.getText().equals(option)) {
                opt.click();
                return;
            }
        }
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Can't find " + option + " in dropdown");
}
```

Note: Selenium's Select() won't work here because your list is not under a 'select' tag.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jake! Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach which parameterizes the selector.

This returns all 3 options:

```
$$("ul.dropdown-menu>li:eq a")
```

This adds a parameter to select which in the list you want:

```
$$("ul.dropdown-menu>li:nth-child(1) a")
```

Then you can map for your tests the child number and pass it into the selector:

```
1 = whatever
2 = whatever
3 = whatever

public void By someDroplist(String selection)
  {
return By.cssSelector("ul.dropdown-menu>li:nth-child(" + selection + ") a");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on how it's selected in the application you either should simulate mouse click with `element.click()` or simulate keydown/keyup event with `element.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);` Also be aware that touch events may handle differently by your application (click may not work)
[Here's a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773944/selenium-webdriver-to-find-the-anchor-tag-and-click-that)

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//ul[@class='dropdown-menu']/li/a")).Click();
```

Comment: Can you please explain what it does?

Comment: you have more examples here - http://hedleyproctor.com/2011/05/tutorial-writing-xpath-selectors-for-selenium-tests/